# C: string manipulations and Arduino

Tags: javascript, c, arduino

I'm learning to program in Arduino and, as far as I understand it, it uses the C language (please correct me if I'm wrong).

I'm a senior in JavaScript and PHP, and now I'm having hard time with simple stuff like string handling.

If in JavaScript I have

```
var c = 33;
var myString = "hello" + c;
alert(myString); //---> hello33
```

how does it work in C/Arduino?

Comment: It's probably best to get [a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), rather than trying to learn the language from scratch by asking questions on SO...

Comment: Specifically, learn about a languages that have stronger typing than JS and PHP.

Comment: No, it uses [Processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_%28programming_language%29) which is similar to C++ and Java

Comment: No, it uses Wiring, which I believe steals the IDE from Processing but uses simplified C++ as the underlying language :-)

Comment: No; actually, it uses both :)   As in "both three of them"

Comment: C++. That's all. The Arduino website hides that, but it is true C++ with a real C++ compiler (avr-gcc). Nothing to do with Processing (which is Java based).

Comment: @Eelvex: The first three paragraphs of Wikipia [Arduino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino) and my own experience support paxdiablo and Vincent - it is basically C++ with some added gimmicks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, you would do something like:

```
char buff[100]; // needs to be large enough.
int c = 33;
sprintf (buff, "hello%d", c); // may want a space after hello

// Now do something with buff.
```

C is a language where you need to manage some low-level details yourself. There's no automatically expanding string type in the base language/library although no doubt there are some good third-party ones around (["better strings"](http://bstring.sourceforge.net/), for example, since it doesn't drag in a lot of other stuff you don't want, particularly important in the embedded space).

Comment: +1. Not sure if `snprintf` is available on Arduino but if it is, it can be used to ensure you don't use more `char` than you're supposed to.

Comment: Should not it be `"hello%d"`?

Comment: Yes, I thought I'd format it a little better but I'll change it back for accuracy (with a note).

Comment: @dreamlax: yes it is, snprintf is available if you add the stdio.h header, as it is included with components from avr-gcc.

Answer (score 2):

Arduino has the built-in [String class](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject), and in that you can do:

```
String stringOne = "A long integer: ";
// using += to add a long variable to a string:
stringOne += 123456789;

// or

stringTwo.concat(123456789);
```

and if both cases you get `"A long integer: 123456789"`.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend to use 2 helper libraries. Those together make using strings so much easier!

PString:
http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1236036180
so you can write...

```
str.print("The temperature is ");
str.print(temp);
str.println(" degrees.");
// do something with str here
```

---

Streaming:
http://arduiniana.org/libraries/streaming/
So you can write...

```
lcd << "GPS #" << gpsno << " date: " << day << "-" << month << "-" << year << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of your JavaScript code as an Arduino sketch is:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  int c = 33;                 // var c = 33;
  String myString = "hello";  // var myString = "hello"
  myString += c;              //                        + c;
  Serial.println(myString);   // alert(myString); //---> hello33
}

void loop() {
}
```

For string handling, the differences between the JavaScript and the Arduino (C++) code are:

- Variables are strongly typed. For example, you need to indicate if a variable is an integer (`int`) or a string (`String`) when you declare it.
- Strings are not built-in 'primitive' types in C++ (and the Arduino version of C++ does not support the C++ standard library string either) so some simple manipulations cannot be performed as a single statement. For example, the assignment and concatenation requires two lines of Arduino code.

Other important differences between your JavaScript and the Arduino (C++) code are:

- You need both a `setup` and `loop` function rather than a `main` function. `setup` runs only once when power is applied to the Arduino board and then `loop` is executed continually.
- The nearest equivalent of JavaScript's `alert` in Arduino is to write to the serial port. To see this output you will need the Arduino board to be connected to a PC. Within the Arduino IDE, turning on the Serial Monitor will allow you to see the output.